# Specifying field names in serializer class acting as another serializer class's field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Suppose for below `ModelSerializer` class

```
class UserSongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user            = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    song_likes      = serializers.ReadOnlyField() # This is model's property field
    song_shares     = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    song_plays      = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    song_price      = serializers.ReadOnlyField()   
    genre           = GenreSerializer(many=True,required=False,context={'key':5})
    language        = LanguageSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

Passing specific `context` kwarg like below

```
genre           = GenreSerializer(many=True,required=False,context={'fields':['name']})
```

Since I want to retrieve only name field in `Genre` model class in some specific cases, I overrided `GenreSerializer` class's `get_fields_name` method so that I can mention specific fields only when required via context

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def get_field_names(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Overriding ModelSerializer get_field_names method for getting only specific fields in serializer when mentioned in SerializerClass arguments
        """

        field_names = self.context.get('fields', None)
        if field_names:
            return field_names

        return super(GenreSerializer, self).get_field_names(*args, **kwargs)        

    class Meta:
        model = Genre
        fields = '__all__'
```

However, I am unable to get any 'fields' (getting `None`) key inside overrided `get_fields_name` method. I know of other ways as well like using `StringRelatedField` but that would change the output representation  to

```
"genre":[
        "Pop",
        "Rock"
        ]
```

Whereas, I want to stick to  my original representation

```
"genre": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Pop",
                    "created_date": "2018-09-05T17:05:59.705422+05:30",
                    "updated_date": "2018-09-20T14:43:02.062107+05:30",
                    "status": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Rock",
                    "created_date": "2018-09-05T17:06:06.889047+05:30",
                    "updated_date": "2018-09-17T16:45:22.684044+05:30",
                    "status": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Classical",
                    "created_date": "2018-09-05T17:06:14.216260+05:30",
                    "updated_date": "2018-09-05T17:06:14.275082+05:30",
                    "status": true
                }
            ]
```

**UPDATE** - What I want is like this

```
"genre": [
                {

                    "name": "Pop"

                },
                {

                    "name": "Rock"

                },
                {

                    "name": "Classical"

                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Contexts are meant to be set to the root serializer only.

Whenever `UserSongSerializer` will be instantiated it'll override the nested `genre` context.

If you are using generic views, you'll want to override the view's `get_serializer_context` and add your own context there. It's documented [at the bottom of the methods section](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods)

PS: context are "shared" to serializers, fields, validators.

PPS: Don't alter context after it's been set you it's going to be sort of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer. Can you suggest workaround for it (using FBVs). I do not want to manually `pop`  `UserSongSerializer(...).data` the fields which I do not want